# MVC Partial view not rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, partial-views

I'm new to MVC and I'm trying to add a partial view to my main layout page so I can show messages throughout my app. I'm having some trouble woring it out:

Here's my layout:

```
<div class="span12">       
<p>
    @{Html.RenderAction("Messaging", "Messaging");}
</p>
@RenderBody()
</div>
```

This is my messaging controller:

```
public ActionResult Messaging()
{
    return PartialView(new ViewModels.Messaging()
        {
            MessageType = Utilities.MessageType.Success,
            MessageHeader = "Test",
            Message = "this is a test message"
        });
}
```

Here is my partial view called _MessagingPartial.cshtml stored in the shared folder:

```
@model AWS.PL.ViewModels.Messaging

<span>
    Model.Message
</span>
```

And here is my ViewModel:

```
public class Messaging
{
    public Utilities.MessageType MessageType { get; set; }
    public string MessageHeader { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I get the error "Partial view Messaging was not found" error. Should the partial view be called Messanging.cshtml or I'm I get the something fundamentally wrong?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks,
Wilky.

Comment: Try this <span>
    @Model.Message
</span>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Here is my partial view called _MessagingPartial.cshtml

Your partial view should be called `Messaging.cshtml` coz that's the name of the controller action that rendered it.

If you want to render a custom partial name, make sure you explicitly specify that:

```
public ActionResult Messaging()
{
    var model = new ViewModels.Messaging
    {
        MessageType = Utilities.MessageType.Success,
        MessageHeader = "Test",
        Message = "this is a test message"
    };
    return PartialView("_MessagingPartial", model);
}
```

and if the partial is located in some non-standard location you could also specify the full path to it:

```
return PartialView("~/Views/FooBar/Baz/_MessagingPartial.cshtml", model);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your guessing is right. Either partial view should be named after calling action, "Messanging.cshtml" in your case, or you should use overload to explicitly supply view name to  [View method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460310%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

```
protected internal ViewResult View(
    string viewName,
    Object model
)
```