# Partial views on _Layout not rendered when Actionfilter invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

The `Alert` view that is rendered contains the layout

```
@model myModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

While using an action filter like so

```
 public class CheckThisAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "Alert",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = new myModel()
                }
            };

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

<strike>the `_Layout` is not reendered at all. (Only the view is rendered)
Why is this so?</strike>
Should i change `ViewResult` to something else, or 
include also the `_Layout` in the action filter somehow?

<strike>**Update**: After inspecting the rendered page, i noticed that the page contains all info, including the _Layout, but chrome denies to render it</strike>

**Update**: The Layout contains other partial views

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="page-inner">
        <partial name="_LeftPanel" />
        <div class="page-content-wrapper">
            <partial name="_PageHeader" />
            <main id="js-page-content" role="main" class="page-content">
                @RenderBody()
            </main>
            <partial name="_PageContentOverlay" />
            <partial name="_PageFooter" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

which do not seem to load at all, and that is the reason why the output is only

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
        <div class="page-inner">
            <div class="page-content-wrapper">
                <main id="js-page-content" role="main" class="page-content">
                   <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                     <strong>Alert!</strong> This is what only is displayed
                   </div>
                </main>
                <div class="page-content-overlay" data-action="toggle" data-class="mobile-nav-on"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/507830/2716623

Comment: I tested your code but it worked well and rendered the all . Do you try to create a new simple project to test the action filter? If you want the community review and debug the code , could you share more details about the view and the way that you apply the filter?

Comment: @XueliChen Could you please check the update?

Comment: @Giulio It renders the _Layout but not the partial views included within it. Just updated it, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507536/return-view-from-actionfilter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17212330/8133866

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following in Visual Studio 2017 .NET Core 2.1 and Visual Studio 2019 .NET Core 3.1.

As far as the action filter is concerned, I've registered it in the `Startup`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddScoped<CheckThisAttribute>();
}
```

and placed it on top of the index action:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(CheckThisAttribute))]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();

    }
```

My `Alert.cshtml` contains only:

```
@model ErrorViewModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
    <strong>Alert!</strong> This is what only is displayed
</div>
```

and the content of such layout is exactly:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="page-inner">
        <div class="page-content-wrapper">
            <partial name="_PageHeader" />
            <main id="js-page-content" role="main" class="page-content">
                @RenderBody()
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, for the sake of simplicity, I've simplified it to just a single, trivial partial view `_PageHeader`:

```
<header>
    <h2>Page Header</h2>
</header>
```

and that header is shown as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Define your PartialView as shown below (Do not define layout page for partialview):

```
<div>
    < ... partial view content goes here >
</div>
```

Add the Action method to the Controller as shown below:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult _DemoPartialView(/* additional parameters */)
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

If you want to open another view e.g. when the request  is not POST, etc. use the following approach:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult _DemoPartialView()
{ 
    if (HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
    else
    {
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder which business logic condition you are checking in CheckThisAttribute filter. 
Instead of overriding ViewName put condition for alert view in layout. 
You can detect condition 2 ways

1. Create base model class for all models and add bool property IsAlert to it. Then  you can set it from action filter.

```js
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
                    {
                        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                        {
                            ViewName = "Alert",
                            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary())
                            {
                                Model = new myModel();
                                Model.IsAlter=true;
                            }
                        };
                        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
                }
```

Then in your layout , refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225315/pass-data-to-layout-that-are-common-to-all-pages)

```
**@model ViewModelBase**
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <div class="page-inner">
            <partial name="_LeftPanel" />
            <div class="page-content-wrapper">
                <partial name="_PageHeader" />
                <main id="js-page-content" role="main" class="page-content">
                    @RenderBody()
                </main>
                @if(Model.IsAlert) 
                 {
                    <partial name="Alert" />
                 }
                <partial name="_PageContentOverlay" />
                <partial name="_PageFooter" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

2. Second approach is to set TempData flag in use it in layout.

```js
 public class CheckThisAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
             filterContext.Controller.TempData.Add("IsAlert","1");
             base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Access TemdData in layout.

```
 @if(TempData["IsAlert"]==1) 
                 {
                    <partial name="Alert" />
                 }
```